# Arduino uno and ttl laser

Tags: arduino-uno, power, wires

I am using my uno with gshield for my cnc. I would like to put laser on it. Laser have 3 wires. Red wire to power supply +, Black wire to power supply -, White wire to Arduino digital pin. I need to Connect the Arduino board ground to power supply -, but don't know how... Simple diagram (like child is using painter) would be great.

Thanks for help,
Urban

Comment: The Arduino board's ground connection is labelled.  Where the ground on the rest of your equipment is, and if it is safe to connect exposed low voltage circuitry such as an Arduino to (particularly if it is safely close to the earth potential or the ground of the AC mains) is a serious question, but one which this site is not the appropriate place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You take a wire, connect one end to the ground on the Arduino board and the other end to the ground on your power supply. Don't forget to strip the insulation. It doesn't get simpler than that.